# MVC 3: Append get parameters on a ActionLink

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, getparameter

I'm using the MVCContrib grid to output some data. When I sort a column, I get a url which may look like this:

```
/?Column=ColumnName&Direction=Ascending
```

Lets say I want to add links to control how many results are being shown. Spontaneously I would write something like this:

```
Html.ActionLink("View 10", "Index", new { pageSize = 10 })
```

... which would give me:

```
/?PageSize=10
```

But say I already sorted the grid. In that case I want to save the url parameters, making the new url look something like this:

```
/?Column=ColumnName&Direction=Ascending&PageSize=10
```

How can accomplish this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could include those other parameters when generating the link:

```
Html.ActionLink(
    "View 10", 
    "Index", 
    new {
        Column = Request["Column"],
        Direction = Request["Direction"],
        pageSize = 10 
    }
)
```

or write a custom html helper which will automatically include all current query string parameters and append the `pageSize` parameter:

```
Html.PaginateLink("View 10", 10)
```

and here's how the helper could look like:

```
public static class HtmlExtensions
{
    public static MvcHtmlString PaginateLink(
        this HtmlHelper helper, 
        string linkText, 
        int pageSize
    )
    {
        var query = helper.ViewContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString;
        var values = query.AllKeys.ToDictionary(key => key, key => (object)query[key]);
        values["pageSize"] = pageSize;
        var routeValues = new RouteValueDictionary(values);
        return helper.ActionLink(linkText, "Index", routeValues);
    }
}
```

Comment: That would work in this specific case, but I was thinking of a more dynamic solution.

Comment: @Bridget the Midget, then a custom HTML helper is the way to go.

Comment: @Bridget the Midget, I have updated my answer to include an example of how the custom HTML helper might look like.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use solution from question [ASP.NET MVC: The right way to propagate query parameter through all ActionLinks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9442494/asp-net-mvc-the-right-way-to-propagate-query-parameter-through-all-actionlinks). It will allow you to preserve any parameters on any routes you like.